# Inconsistency in Google Custom Search API Results for URL Verification

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, seo, developer-tools

I hope you're doing well. I'm reaching out because I've run into an issue with the Google Custom Search JSON API that I believe some of you might have insights on.

**Issue Overview:**
I'm currently using the API to verify if specific URLs are indexed on Google. However, I've noticed a significant mismatch between the results obtained from the API and the actual Google search results.

**Example URL:**
For instance, the URL https://www.streamingmediaglobal.com/PressRelease/Filmzie-Streaming-Service-Launches-on-Samsung-TV-Plus_51658.aspx shows up in the Google search results when checked manually. But, the API doesn't seem to reflect the same information.

**API/Service Details:**

- Service Name: customsearch.googleapis.com
- Purpose: The API is crucial for my app, providing users with information on the index status of their backlinks on Google.

**Request Method:**
I use the Custom Search JSON API, employing the Google Search Syntax `site:<Url>` to determine a URL's presence on Google.

**Impact:**
This inconsistency is affecting the accuracy of the data presented to my users, causing confusion.

**Request for Assistance:**
If any of you have experience with this or know of a potential solution, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Let's collaborate to ensure the API provides accurate and up-to-date results.

Thanks a bunch!

Best,
Ankur Chaurasia

I am trying to get the best solution of this problem.